# Javascript: как удалять результат выполнения функции при следующем вызове

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, адаптивность

Прикрутил на сайте виджет ВК "Сообщества". Стояла задача сделать его адаптивным, при этом ширина должна не просто подстраиваться под родительский блок при перезагрузке страницы, а именно тянуться при изменении размера экрана.

Решил использовать window.onresize:

```html
<script src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?143" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="vk">
  <div id="vk_groups"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = function() {
      var vk = document.getElementById('vk');
      var wid = vk.offsetWidth;
      VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {
        width: wid,
        height: "300"
      }, 1);
    };
    window.onresize();
  </script>
</div>
```

Задача с адаптивностью решена, но появилась проблема: при каждом изменении размера экрана функция VK.Widgets.Group вызывается с новой шириной, при этом прежний блок с виджетом (со старыми размерами) остаётся на странице. И так их число растёт...

Как сделать, чтобы при изменении размера экрана результаты предыдущего вызова VK.Widgets.Group удалялись?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вроде работает. Попробуй так.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?143" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div id="vk"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var vk = document.getElementById('vk');
    window.onresize = function() {
      vk.innerHTML = '<div id="vk_groups"></div>';
      VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {
        width: vk.offsetWidth,
        height: "300"
      }, 1);
    };
    window.onresize();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Может, Вы и с этим вопросом сможете помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653327/ Я писал в техподдержку ВКонтакте, но они не смогли дать рабочий вариант.